# NodeJS, Socket.io - The websocket getting disconnected immediately after getting connected

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, next.js, socket.io

- I have my backend in NodeJS and frontend in NextJS. As soon I try to connect with the server for a WebSocket connection, the server connects the socket and immediately disconnects it.
- This is what I get on my server as soon as I reload my frontend page:
  `user connected ----  OKGG9r0qvvBs0EWeAAAB test@test.com  socket disconnected--- OKGG9r0qvvBs0EWeAAAB test@test.com`
- This is my server code:

```
import express from "express";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import http from "http";
import { Server, Socket } from "socket.io";
import userRoutes from "./routes/users";
import { DefaultEventsMap } from "socket.io/dist/typed-events";

dotenv.config();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = new Server(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: process.env.CLIENT_URL,
  },
});

app.use(express.json());

app.get("/ping", (req, res) => res.status(200).send("Pong"));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET");
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With"
  );
  next();
});

interface SType extends Socket {
  email?: string;
}

io.use((socket: SType, next) => {
  const userEmail = socket.handshake.auth.email;
  if (!userEmail) {
    return next(new Error("Invalid email"));
  }
  console.log("userEmail-----", userEmail);
  socket.email = userEmail;
  next();
});

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  const users = [];
  for (let [id, socket] of io.of("/").sockets) {
    users.push({
      userID: id,
      email: (socket as any).email,
    });
    socket.emit("users", users);
  }

  socket.broadcast.emit("user connected", {
    userID: socket.id,
    email: (socket as any).email,
  });
  console.log("user connected ---- ", socket.id, (socket as any).email);

  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    console.log("socket disconnected---", socket.id, (socket as any).email);
    (socket as any).email = "";
  });
});

app.use("/users", userRoutes);

server.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`server running on port ${PORT}`));
```

this is code on client side

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (userState) {
    socket.auth = { email: userState.email };
  }
}, [userState]);
useEffect(() => {
  socket.on("users", (users: any) => {
    console.log("users", users);
    setUsers(users);
  });
  socket.on("user connected", (user: any) => {
    setUsers((previousState: any) => [...previousState, user]);
  });
}, [socket]);
```

- I tried the solutions from stack overflow as well as socket.io documentation, but nothing seems to work. Does anyone know what is happening here?

Comment: can you pls paste your client socket connection code?

Comment: @Yilmaz, sure.
```
useEffect(() => {
    if (userState) {
      socket.auth = { email: userState.email };
    }
  }, [userState]);

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("users", (users: any) => {
      console.log("users", users);
      setUsers(users);
    });

    socket.on("user connected", (user: any) => {
      setUsers((previousState: any) => [...previousState, user]);
    });
  }, [socket]);
```